# Get custom response from PHP for Jquery file uploader

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I want to get a custom response from PHP service for jquery file upload.

```
<?php

//database query to insert data

$sql_params['document_name'] = name;
$sql_params['document_location'] =document_location;
$sql_params['document_size'] = document_size;
$sql_params['document_id'] = $document_id;

echo json_encode($sql_params);

?>
```

Javascript Code:

```
           this.$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                add: function(e, data) {
                    var filename = data.files[0].name;

                    var jqXHR = data.submit()
                        .success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(result);
                            console.log(textStatus);
                        })
                        .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        }).complete(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log('complete');
                            console.log(result);
                        });
                },
                done: function(e, data) {

                    console.log(data.result);
                },

                progressall: function(e, data) {

                }
            });

            this.$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
                url: 'api/app/file',
                maxFileSize: 100000,
                acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(txt|pdf|doc|docx|jpg|gif|xls|xlsx|rtf)$/i
            });
```

I want to get the json reponse as:

```
{"document_name":"file (9).txt","document_location":"location","document_size":2720,"document_id":"44"}
```

But I am always getting:

```
[{"name":"file (9).txt","size":2720,"type":"text\/plain","url":"location","delete_url":"some URL","delete_type":"DELETE"}]
```

Comment: Could you please open firebug console on browser and see the ajax response data? I mean whole response.

Comment: Yeah I can see the response data. But there are two post requests for same URL and both the ajax response are present there.

Comment: Please put them in your question in order to analyze

Comment: I have already posted both the JSON responses. Please tell me anything you need.

Comment: By the way, that is the default response due to blueimp. Why do you want to get custom response?

Comment: I want to get the ID of the file which is inserted into database.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting default response due to Blueimp. You can get latest file from db with another ajax query in blueimp like;

```
.....
add: function(e, data) {
    var filename = data.files[0].name;

    var jqXHR = data.submit()
        .success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(result);
            console.log(textStatus);
        })
        .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }).complete(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "getlatestfile.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: "url=" + result[0].url, // this is unique url of uploaded file
                success: function(response) {
                    //response has doc id
                }

            });
        });
}
....
```

and in your php handler;

**getlatestfile.php**

```
<?php
......
if (empty($_POST["url"])) {
    die("Url must be specified");
} 

$url = $_POST["url"];

$sql = "SELECT *FROM your_table WHERE url = $url ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
// get $result
echo $result;
```